# Wordpress Form Dropdown Menu not clickable

Tags: wordpress

The dropdown menu (pick list) is no longer clickable.

Here is the code

```
<form id="salesforce_w2l_lead_4_sidebar" class="w2llead sidebar top-aligned" method="post" action="#salesforce_w2l_lead_4_sidebar" _lpchecked="1">
    <div class="sf_field sf_field_first_name sf_type_text"> 
        <label class="w2llabel required  text" for="sf_first_name">First name: <sup><span class="required">*</span></sup></label>   
        <input placeholder="" value="" id="sf_first_name" class="w2linput text" name="first_name" type="text" mouseev="true" keyev="true" style="cursor: auto;">
    </div>
    <div class="sf_field sf_field_last_name sf_type_text">  
        <label class="w2llabel required  text" for="sf_last_name">Last name: <sup><span class="required">*</span></sup></label> 
        <input placeholder="" value="" id="sf_last_name" class="w2linput text" name="last_name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="sf_field sf_field_company sf_type_text">    
        <label class="w2llabel   text" for="sf_company">Company:</label>    
        <input placeholder="" value="" id="sf_company" class="w2linput text" name="company" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="sf_field sf_field_title sf_type_text">  
        <label class="w2llabel   text" for="sf_title">Title:</label>    
        <input placeholder="" value="" id="sf_title" class="w2linput text" name="title" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="sf_field sf_field_email sf_type_text">  
        <label class="w2llabel required  text" for="sf_email">Email: <sup><span class="required">*</span></sup></label>
        <input placeholder="" value="" id="sf_email" class="w2linput text" name="email" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="sf_field sf_field_00NA0000008rkLE sf_type_select">  
        <label class="w2llabel required  select" for="sf_00NA0000008rkLE">I am interested in...: <sup><span class="required">*</span></sup></label>     
        <select id="sf_00NA0000008rkLE" class="w2linput select" name="00NA0000008rkLE"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="sf_field sf_field_description sf_type_textarea">    
        <label class="w2llabel   textarea" for="sf_description">Comments:</label>       
        <textarea id="sf_description" class="w2linput textarea" name="description" placeholder=""></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="sf_field sf_field_captcha sf_type_captcha">
        <label class="w2llabel">Type the text shown: *</label>              
        <img class="w2limg" src="http://rocket-space.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=sfw2l_get_captcha&amp;_CAPTCHA=true&amp;t=0.32436700+1395829007&amp;hash=981524cfc3ec488d5a0671c5467b785ed9733c40" alt="CAPTCHA image">
        <input type="text" class="w2linput text captcha" name="captcha_text" value=""><input type="hidden" class="w2linput hidden" name="captcha_hash" value="981524cfc3ec488d5a0671c5467b785ed9733c40">
    </div>  
        <input type="text" name="message" class="w2linput" value="" style="display: none;"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="form_id" class="w2linput" value="4"> 
    <div class="w2lsubmit">
        <input type="submit" name="w2lsubmit" class="w2linput submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown list isn't working because you have no options in it.

```
<div class="sf_field sf_field_00NA0000008rkLE sf_type_select">  
    <label class="w2llabel required  select" for="sf_00NA0000008rkLE">I am interested in...: <sup><span class="required">*</span></sup></label>     
    <select id="sf_00NA0000008rkLE" class="w2linput select" name="00NA0000008rkLE"></select>
</div>
```

You need to add options to a select list. For [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vGAP4/):

```
<div class="sf_field sf_field_00NA0000008rkLE sf_type_select">  
    <label class="w2llabel required  select" for="sf_00NA0000008rkLE">I am interested in...: <sup><span class="required">*</span></sup></label>     
    <select id="sf_00NA0000008rkLE" class="w2linput select" name="00NA0000008rkLE">
        <option value="car">Car</option>
        <option value="bike">Bike</option>
        <option value="lorry">Lorry</option>
    </select>
</div>
```